# Python Iterations?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to run a simulation in Python, whereby I graph a random walk for an array given a set level for two variable parameters.

However, I am having a problem in that I am not sure how to iterate so that 250 different random numbers are generated to plug into a formula. e.g. I have defined a random number x, but since it is only one random number, Python will then generate a graph of a straight line since the formula is only taking one variable into account.

For 250 data points, the program needs 250 random numbers between 0 and 1 generated to be able to run a random process on the data. However, I am not sure where to go from here and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

**New:**
Given that my understanding of volatility is correct, it is only the standard deviation of the mean return, correct? Then all you need to do is get a normally distributed random number with mean *mu* and standard deviation *v*. As Severin pointed out there is a function in numpy to do just that, namely *numpy.random.normal(loc,scale)* where *loc=mu* and *scale=v*. See example below. I've tried to explicitly code each step. Once you are comfortable with numpy/python you can do most of it in 1 or 2 lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Initial parameters:
#-------------------
# mean return per step
mu = 0.1
# volatility
v = 0.06
# starting stock price
s0 = 500

# Looks like compound annual growth rate, but isn't that exactly what you want
# to determine from the simulation?
k = mu-(v**2)/2

# Iterate random walk, assuming no history within the changes.
stock_price_changes = []
for t in xrange(250):
    rnd = np.random.normal(loc=mu,scale=v)
    stock_price_changes.append(rnd)

# Add up all stock changes and add the initial stock price
stock_total = np.cumsum(stock_price_changes) + s0

# Plot the whole thing
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7),edgecolor='k',facecolor='w')
plt.plot(np.arange(250),stock_total,c='k')
plt.xlabel('Trading Days')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Old:**
Maybe I don't really understand this question properly, but you don't want to code a 'real' random walk right? It's rather just adding randomness to your exponential model? I guess the easiest way to do this is to use numpy, which you already import. You can squeeze the random number generation in like this:

```
...
k = mu-(v**2)/2

t=np.arange(0,250)
s1=s0*np.exp(k*t/250) #+(v*datapoints)*np.sqrt(t/250)

rndScaling = 1.0
s1 += rndScaling * 2.0 * (np.random.rand(250) - 0.5)
...
```

The 2.0 * (np.random.rand(250) - 0.5) expression yields an array with 250 random variables between -1 and +1. Now if you want a 'randomness' with an amplitude of say 2.0 around your exponential model you just change rndScale to 2.0.

Comment: This is a Brownian Motion type model. I just reviewed what I'm trying to do from the Excel file; I am trying to get the inverse of the standard normal distribution for each random number in the observation; i.e. equivalent to NORMSINV() in Excel. So, in the formula s1=s0*np.exp(k*t/250) #+(v*datapoints)*np.sqrt(t/250), I want the datapoints variable to refer to this number. I would appreciate any advice as I am still quite lost.

Comment: I see. So what you really want to do is draw a random number from a normal distribution with mean mu and standard deviation v? At least if I am reading the wiki entry for volatility correctly. See updated post then.

Comment: I am currently trying to run the code, but just to advise that I am getting a ValueError for the line: plt.plot(np.arange(250),stock_total,c='k').

Answer (score 0):

That answer changes depending on how you want the random numbers applied.

But you can do something like this:

```
tt=np.arange(0,250)
s1=[(s0+random())*np.exp(k*t/250) for t in tt]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need for Brownian motion simulation is to get vector of normally distributed (a.k.a. gaussian) random numbers. You don't need any normal inverse like in Excel, but call to

```
v = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, 250)
```

You'll get back vector of N(0,1) distributed numbers. More details at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

UPDATE

B. Scholz code looks good to me...